# VB.NET Progress bar percentage

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar, transparent, percentage

I created a progress bar which works perfectly. I recently added percentages but I'd like to display the label on top of the progress bar.

Like so:

[image]

The only problem as you can see is that the background is not transparent. Dispite having:

```
lblPercentage.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

on form load... Is there something that can be done for this?

Comment: http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/using-components-controls/7959-text-inside-progressbar.html

Comment: This link has the complete source code for how to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Transparent BackColor actually works. The problem is that the label gets its BackColor from the form, since the form is its Parent. Therefore we must make the progress bar its parent and adapt its location as well, since now it must be specified relative to the progress bar. Add this code to your form:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim pos As Point = PointToScreen(lblPercentage.Location)
    pos = myProgressBar.PointToClient(pos)
    lblPercentage.Parent = myProgressBar
    lblPercentage.Location = pos
    lblPercentage.BackColor = Color.Transparent
End Sub
```

Alternatively you can calculate the location of the label like this

```
lblPercentage.Location = New Point(lblPercentage.Location.X - myProgressBar.Location.X,
                                   lblPercentage.Location.Y - myProgressBar.Location.Y)
```

You cannot make this in the designer, since your progress bar is probably not a container control (i.e. placing a label on it does not make it a child control of the bar) and you will not see the result in the designer.

---

**UPDATE**

You could also try these alternatives:

- Draw the percentage number in the `OnPaint` method of your control (override `OnPaint`).
- Do what I showed you above inside the progress bar. You could add the label programmatically in the constructor of the progress bar.
- Use a `UserControl` as base class of your progress bar. This would allow you to place the label on it in the designer.

Comment: Oh I must change the back color of the progress bar now. The problem is I cannot put the progress bar back color to transparent ... Is there a way around this?

Comment: The back color of the progress bar is not relevant (choose any color you like), only the back color of the label must be transparent.

Comment: That's odd ... When I change the backcolor of the progress bar it reflects the backcolor of the label. The label is set to transparent.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused on how to use the OnPaint method and UserControl class. I'll need to look more into it and see if I can make something work

Answer (score 1):

here you have made your progress bar transparent that means it transparent only to progress bar and behind the progress bar there is form, thats why it showing form.
It's a Windows restriction that transparency effects are relative to the top-level window, stacking effects do not work.always You will see the `form` as the background,

Comment: So there's no way to make the label transparent with the progress bar instead of the form?