# how to make trasparent percentage in visual basic?

Tags: percentage

there would be a way to create a transparent percentage that overlaps the progress bar? 
As in this topic:

[VB.NET Progress bar percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243225/vb-net-progress-bar-percentage)

(see the image)

you can see the image, but the user has not resolved.

You can do this with the latest code updates?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET Progress bar percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243225/vb-net-progress-bar-percentage)

Comment: but doesn't have a solution. Please, help me.